# Formatting Windows 7 without CD

Tags: windows-7, formatting

I have a Windows 7 laptop that I need to return to my former employer.  I worked there for about 10 years, so I'd like to nuke the laptop before I return it since it might contain personal info in there somewhere.

Is there any reasonable way to wipe the laptop before I return it short of sticking the whole thing on a giant magnet?

BTW - I don't have a Windows 7 CD

Comment: Boot off a USB/CD/Whatever with [DBAN](http://www.dban.org/) and kill that thing.

Answer (score 1):

what type of computer is it? Most computers, if not completely wiped before (likely for company computers) have partitions in the Hard drive that you can restore it to.

Comment: It's a Dell Latitude e5430.  I only see a C:\ and D:\ (DVD) drive, unless the partition is hidden...

Comment: I do not understand your answer here....